# Setup IPv4 local on IPv6 VPS

Tags: ipv6, bridge, openvz, ipv4

I have a dedicated server running multiple IPv6 only OpenVZ containers. I want them to be able to communicate with the IPv4 internet, but I realized that isn't going to be possible with IPv6 only. So they need to have an IPv4 address as well, not sure if a local address will work for it, but pretty sure it should.

I added 169.254.1.100 in the container .conf file, but when I try to start it, I get this:

```
Adding IP address(es): (the IPv6 address) 169.254.1.100
arpsend: 169.254.1.100 is detected on another computer : 00:04:9b:f2:b0:00
vps-net_add WARNING: arpsend -c 1 -w 1 -D -e 169.254.1.100 eth0 FAILED
```

I did a lot of research, and searched Serve Fault before posting this, but found nothing relating to this.

Answer (score 2):

Something else on your network already has that address specifically the host with MAC address 00:04:9b:f2:b0:00 (which appears to be a [Cisco address](http://hwaddress.com/?q=00:04:9b:f2:b0:00)).

The 169.254/16 network is reserved for IPv4 Link-Local addresses as explained in [RFC3927](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3927) so you should not be manually assigning addresses in that range.

You should use 192.168/16, 172.16/12, or 10/8 for private addressing and have a suitably configured router.